# How to improve on my Division program? (Easy Python)

Tags: python, division

I am currently trying to make a division program which asks random division questions. There are 2 things blocking me from doing so: 1)My program thinks that everything divided by something is always 0. e.g. 8 divided by 2 = 0. 2) I need to make division without a floating point, like 144/5. So here it is:

```
import sys 
import random

guessRight=0
guessWrong=0

while True: 
    num1 = random.randint(0,12)    #probably messed up here
    num2 = random.randint(12,144)  #and here  
    print "To exit this game type 'exit'" 
    theyputinstuffhere = raw_input("What is " + str(num2) + " divided by " + str(num1) + "? ") #maybe messed up here


    if theyputinstuffhere == "exit":
        print "Now exiting game!"
        sys.exit()

    elif int(theyputinstuffhere) == num1/num2: #maybe messed this whole elif too
        print num1/num2
        print "Correct!"
        guessRight=guessRight+1
        print "You have gotten " + str(guessRight) + " answer(s) right and you got " + str(guessWrong) + " wrong"
    else:
        print "Wrong! The correct answer is: " + str(num1/num2)
        guessWrong=guessWrong+1
        print "You have gotten " + str(guessRight) + " answer(s) right and you got " + str(guessWrong) + " wrong"
```

This is what it currently prints:

```
To exit this game type 'exit'
What is 34 divided by 11? #I type any number (e.g. 3)
Wrong! The correct answer is: 0
You have gotten 0 answer(s) right and you got 1 wrong
```

Comment: `num1` will always be smaller than `num2`. You might have mixed up the values.

Comment: Note that the prompt ("num2 divided by num1") and the check (num1/num2) are not saying the same thing.

Comment: @Matthias Looking at the input line, that seems to be exactly the case. In that line it prints `<num2>/<num1>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking for num2 divided by num1, then you need to use `num2/num1` in your code, not `num1/num2`.  This is also why you are always getting `0`, `num1` will always be less than `num2` so `num1/num2` will be `0` when integer division is used (which is the default for dividing ints on Python 2.x).

To avoid questions like 144/5 and eliminate the division by zero issue you can use the following:

```
num1 = random.randint(1,12)
num2 = random.randint(1,12) * num1
```

Comment: F.J. I see my mistake, but whenever it asks me something like, 144/0, when I answer it, it says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./division.py", line 19, in <module>
    elif int(theyputinstuffhere) == num2/num1:
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Comment: Also, it asks weird questions, like 144/5, which is ... not what I want, what I want is 144/12 or 24/6 or something like that...

Comment: I see, the 'ZeroDivisionError' could be solved by changing the 0 to 1 on the eighth line of code.

Comment: BUT IT STILL ASKS WEIRD QUESTIONS!

Comment: @user2468523 it throws an error when you do 144/0 because that's an illegal math operation. any number / 0 doesn't exist